# LINQ Query not working properly ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing a LINQ query to get the queues of an agent and then removing rows that match a specific criteria but the web page displays the entire list.

```
var agentQueues = _context.AgentQueues.Where(e => e.AgentId == Request.AgentId)
                                .OrderByDescending(e => e.ScheduleTime)
                                .ThenBy(e => e.AgentQueueId)
                                .ToList();

agentQueues.RemoveAll(e => !e.Status.Equals("Waiting") && !e.Status.Equals("Running") && !e.Deleted==false);
```

Even though I am writing RemoveAll, the query still displays rows that contain Statuses other than 'Running' and 'Waiting'.
It would be great if anyone could point me to the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to this, use `||` instead of `&&` for status

```
    agentQueues.RemoveAll((e => !e.Status.Equals("Waiting") || 
!e.Status.Equals("Running")) && !e.Deleted==false);
```